# loading comments from active row cells on to userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, comments, userform

I am trying to update comments from my active row by using the userform textbox. The code is defined in module and on double click on the row in a defined range (worksheet double click function) the userfrom is shown with the comments from active row.

So far, the code works fine without error only in case when there are comments in column 3 and 4 of the active row. I get a run-time error 91 when the columns of active row do not have comments. Can somebody help me?

```
Sub UpdateMYUF()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row  
TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Comment.Text))  
TextBox4.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Comment.Text))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is following solution:

```
If Not ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Comment Is Nothing Then
          .TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Comment.Text))
```